# Can't use localhost url with axios?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am trying to perform a GET on an endpoint I have running.  If I access the endpoint via browser I get a JSON object like I should, but if I try to do it as the frontend client I get a 404.

This works:

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.request))
  .then(response => {
    this.$el.textContent = JSON.stringify(response.data)
  })
```

This doesn't work:

```
axios.get('127.0.0.1:3000/api/info')
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.request))
  .then(response => {
    this.$el.textContent = JSON.stringify(response.data)
  })
```

Comment: did not you tried to write url like that 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/info' , as I see you have missed the http part in url

Comment: or at least `//127.0.0.1:3000/api/info`

Comment: Please define _"doesn't work"_. What happens? What errors are reported (if any)?

Comment: @MohammedOmer That was it, thank you!

Comment: @Phil I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call api in mobile device? If yes you have to set bind ip. If you don't set you can't access api on mobile device.